# Iterate values of an attribute with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML-structure like

```
<Object id="id0000" link="id0010 id0020">
    <Data id="id1000">
      <DataValue name="Obj0000"/>
    </Data>
</Object>
```

I have several 'Object'-nodes, some of them have one link, some of them have two or more links. The links (ids) are separated by a white space. I already used the 'tokenize()'-function, to get the individual link ids

```
<xsl:variable name="links">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Each link refers to another 'Object' with some data.

Now I want to use the position of the link (ids) as a string, so my output should look something like

```
<Object>
    <hasName>Obj0000</hasName>
    <hasStartLink>id0010</hasStartLink>
</Object>

<LinkedObject>
    <hasID>id0010</hasID>
    <hasDescription>1. link of Obj0000</hasDescription>
    <hasNextLink>id0020</hasNextLink>
</LinkedObject>
<LinkedObject>
    <hasID>id0020</hasID>
    <hasDescription>2. link of Obj0000</hasDescription>
</LinkedObject>
```

I found many pages that said, iterating and saving the current position is something that cannot be done in this way, one has to work around somehow. I found something like

```
<!-- inside another template -->
    <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
<!-- end of another template -->

<xsl:template name="LinkedObj">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>

    <!-- do some stuff here -->
    <!-- use '$count' as position -->

    <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

But now I don't know at with point I could use such a template. I'd rather not call the template again in the template itself but in "another template". But inside this ("another") template I don't have the current count-variable, right?
In the 'LinkedObj'-template I'm already in another context so I don't know how many times I should call another template (I have no 'links').
Currently I'm doing it with two parameters so I'm checking if my position is less than the number of attributes (links):

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
    <xsl:element name="Object>
        <xsl:element name="hasName">
            <xsl:value-of select="Data/DataValue/@name"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="hasStartLink">
            <!-- here I'm also not sure how to get only the first separated id -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(tokenize(@link, ' '))"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LinkedObj">
    <xsl:param name="position"/>
    <xsl:param name="count"/>

    <!-- do some stuff here -->
    <!-- use '$position' as position -->

    <xsl:if test="$position &lt; $count">
        <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Any suggestions on this?

The next step would be not only to get the position and use it for a text output but to use the id of the links to call or apply new templates. As I commented in the last code block I don't know how to use the elements of a tokenized string as a node. I tried it with a for-each element but I did not work that way because there was some context-error (I have to reproduce it and post it here).

EDIT:
I found a way to get it working, which differs from Tobias's idea, so I'm posting the basic code here:

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
    <xsl:element name="Object>
        <xsl:element name="hasName">
            <xsl:value-of select="Data/DataValue/@name"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="hasStartLink">
            <!-- here I'm also not sure how to get only the first separated id -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(tokenize(@link, ' '))"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="links" select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LinkedObj">
    <xsl:param name="position"/>
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:param name="links"/>

    <xsl:element name="hasID">
        <xsl:value-of select="$links[$position]"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="hasDescription">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($position, '. link of ', Data/DataValue/@name)"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:if test="$position &lt; $count">
        <xsl:element name="hasNextLink">
            <xsl:value-of select="$links[$position + 1]"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="links" select="$links"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case it is possible to get the values of "Object" inside the "LinkedObj" template, since the template is called with a node (the "Object", as the context does not change).

Comment: As I'm now (as written above) using a 'call-template' instead of 'apply-template' my context does not change so now I'm able to write `<xsl:with-param name="links" select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>` in the calling template. In the called template I can now write `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Object[@id=$links[$position]]" mode="Link"/>`. The position will always get the current link as it is incremented in this template.

Comment: I added an answer, just as a sidenote, do not use `<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>` inside the variable, this will just give you the same string again, either use `xsl:sequence`or use the variable's select attribute.

Comment: I'm currently using
`<xsl:with-param name="links" select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>`
when calling my "LinkedObj" template. Inside this template I'm using the parameter "position" (will be incremented) to get the content of the tokenized string like `$links[$position]`.
So maybe I don't get the whole point: my tokenized string, stored in  the parameter "link" is basically just one string (separated into an array of substrings). I want to access different substrings each time I'm calling the "LinkedObj" template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple Objects I added a root element to your source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
<Object id="id0000" link="id0010 id0020">
    <Data id="id1000">
        <DataValue name="Obj0000"/>
    </Data>
</Object>
</Objects>
```

You don't have to use a recursive call off the LinkedObj template, you can just iterate over the links and call in the loop:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Objects">
    <Objects>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object"/>
    </Objects>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Object">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="Data/DataValue/@name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="links" select="tokenize(@link, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:element name="Object">
        <xsl:element name="hasName">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="hasStartLink">
            <xsl:value-of select="$links[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:for-each select="$links">
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="LinkedObj">
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nextLink" select="$links[$position + 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="objectName" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LinkedObj">
    <xsl:param name="position"/>
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:param name="nextLink"/>
    <xsl:param name="objectName"/>
    <LinkedObject>
        <hasID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
        </hasID>
        <hasDescription>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>. link of </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$objectName"/>
        </hasDescription>
        <xsl:if test="$nextLink!=''">
            <hasNextLink>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nextLink"/>
            </hasNextLink>
        </xsl:if>
    </LinkedObject>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
   <Object>
      <hasName>Obj0000</hasName>
      <hasStartLink>id0010</hasStartLink>
   </Object>
   <LinkedObject>
      <hasID>id0010</hasID>
      <hasDescription>1. link of Obj0000</hasDescription>
      <hasNextLink>id0020</hasNextLink>
   </LinkedObject>
   <LinkedObject>
      <hasID>id0020</hasID>
      <hasDescription>2. link of Obj0000</hasDescription>
   </LinkedObject>
</Objects>
```

Allthough this was the required output structure, not sure if this is correct, I'm guessing the LinkedObjects should be within each Object, however that change is trivial...

Comment: I tried to use your idea until I realized that I have to pass each attribute and node, that I want to process later as a parameter, since the template is called with a string instead of a node.
I got it working my way but now I'm wondering if it's worth the effort to change my code to use your idea. I think this has something to do with "the common way to do such a task" - and I don't know the common way.